# UINavigationBar back button not showing on iPhone X iOS 11

Tags: uinavigationbar, ios11, xcode9, swift3.2

I am facing an issue, When i run my app on iPhone SE simulator it shows back button on nav bar like this.

[image]

But when i run the same app on iPhone X, iPhone 8 and iPhone 8 plus iOS 11 and XCode 9 there is no back button on nav bar and its for all ViewControllers not for specific viewController. Here is the example

[image]

Can anyone tell why is this happening.

Comment: How do you set up the back button?

Comment: let backButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.leftNavigationButton)
            
            self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backButtonItem, animated: false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some effort i came to know that i am setting the view's leading space before setting as NavBarTitleView

```
navView.viewLeadingConstraint.constant = (UIDevice().isIPhone5 || UIDevice().isIPhone4) ? -15:-40
```

due to above code my back button hides so i removed above line of code and add following method in NavView which resolve my problem.

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue where the back button was only a little bit. In the debugging console it was showing a few broken constraints in the navigation bar.

I found this line in the app delegate to be the issue.

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment( // Remove the text "Back" from the back button so only the back arrow is visible
        UIOffset(horizontal: -100, vertical:-100),
        for: UIBarMetrics.default
    )
```

try and find any appearance api calls in your code and see if you might be modifying the bar button offsets.